# Gathering information about akka system

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor system that is behaving sluggishly, and would like to monitor it from a web interface, using an akka actor I created that serves up REST responses over Jetty. I have flipped through the akka ActorSystem API and haven't been able to find any classes/functions that do this. I would like to gather:

1. Which actors are currently processing messages
2. Which actors have queued messages but are waiting for CPU time
3. How much memory each actor is using

Comment: Sounds like the Typesafe Console (http://typesafe.com/platform/runtime/console) - I believe it is free for developers (don't quote me on that)

Comment: Also note that there are more metrics available than the Typesafe Console UI itself shows. You can access these by querying atmos directly on the reporting node (by posting JSON objects).